# Different HREF if I click on the link and if I set an auto click

Tags: javascript

When I don't set the auto click script, I load the page, click on the link and go to the right URL. If I add the script to auto click, instead of redirecting me to the same URL that when I clicked, it adds the HREF to the URL where the link is, and don't take me anywhere. Anyone could help me to make the auto click behave in the same way as when I click? Thanks in advance.

Here you can see what I meant: https://rioga.webflow.io/bem-vindo

*Code with Auto click on*

```
<body><a id="redirect" href="#/ms/member-page/default" class="w-button">Button Text</a>
  <div class="w-embed w-script">
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("redirect").click();
</script>
  </div>
  <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js?site=5e79526aa1d3ba459f1ebac2" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
</body>
```

Comment: @Antonie553 this is a custom link from a plugin (MemberStack) that redirects me to the member page. If I remove the #, it adds the "/ms/member-page/default" to my domain (https://rioga.webflow.io/ms/member-page/default) and doesn't redirect me to the member page. If I don't set an auto click and click on the link, then it takes me to the right address.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, it's not redirecting you cause you're using `#` in your link. Usually it's using like an anchor for linking to an element on the same page.

You can try:

`window.location.replace("https://rioga.webflow.io/bem-vindo/ms/member-page/default");` – if you need it to work as an HTTP redirect

or

`window.location.href = "https://rioga.webflow.io/bem-vindo/ms/member-page/default";` - as clicking on a link